# MySQL - Update last occurrence of string

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
 +----------------------------+
 | id    | name     |  helper |
 +----------------------------+
 |    1  | user1    |    NULL |
 |    2  | user1    |    NULL |
 |    3  | user1    |    NULL |
 |    4  | user2    |    NULL |
 |    5  | user2    |    NULL |
 +----------------------------+
```

Now I want to update the ***LAST*** occurrence of **"user1"** - how do I do that?

This is my example query right now:

```
    UPDATE Table SET helper = 'bob' WHERE name = 'user1' AND helper IS NULL;
```

However, this updates all the "user1" Entries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing `order by` and `limit` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update t set helper = 'bob' where name = 'user1' order by id desc limit 1;
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/110ce/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: This works. Don't know why the other answer got 2 up votes..
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
UPDATE Table SET helper = 'bob' WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table WHERE name = 'user1')
```

Just use MAX(id) to get the last row of 'user1'.

Comment: Should work if you put your table name in.  Can you show me the syntax error you get?

Comment: "You can't specify target table 'Table' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: 3 up votes for a query that doesn't work? I'm jealous!